# Axios Request Param not accepting params

Tags: reactjs, https, parameters, react-redux, axios

I am working on a post HTTP call, when trying with the postman, my services return 200OK status and create a rating for the element. 
here is the snapshot of the postman: 
[image]

but seems like my function has some errors, it's not working the way it's supposed to:

Could anybody help me identify the bug:

my action:

```
export cost addRating = (params, access_token, callback) => async dispatch => {
   await axios.post(`/userpreference/feedback?rating=${params.rating}&title=${params.title}&assetId={params.assetId}` , 
   { headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token}
})
.then(res => { 
    dispatch({
            type: ADD_RATING_TO_REPORT
            payload: res.data
    });
   callback(); 
 });
}
```

Component I am using this function:

```
handleClick = (rating, title, feedback, assetId) => {
  const rating ={
   rating,
   title, 
   feedback,
   assetId
  }; 
  this.props.addRating(rating, this.props.user.access_token); 
}



render() {
  return (
   <li onClick={() => this.handleClick("2", "my Title", "My feedback", "32546")} > <DisplayRating/> </li>
 )
}
}
```

Comment: Here you send two parameters this.props.addRating(rating, this.props.user.access_token),  but in your action there are 3 input parameters.

Comment: How is your function behaving? Are you getting an error? Or can you try logging the response from the server?

Comment: We had to change our services since the body was empty,post-call was actually placing authentication header param in body.